# Simlpexml and registerxpathnamespace issue with soap response body

Tags: php, xpath, namespaces, simplexml

Here is the xml: (**a.xml**)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:ser="http://www.example.com/v1/services">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest>
            <ser:buyer>
                <ser:buyerId>1233</ser:buyerId>
                <ser:toCountry>IN</ser:toCountry>
                <ser:toZip>110001</ser:toZip>
            </ser:buyer>
            <ser:item>
                <ser:id>25164</ser:id>
                <ser:categoryId>15032</ser:categoryId>
                <ser:seller>
                    <ser:sellerId>11997</ser:sellerId>
                    <ser:fromCountry>IN</ser:fromCountry>
                </ser:seller>
                <ser:transactionId>0</ser:transactionId>
            </ser:item>
        </ser:getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The PHP code to parse this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file( 'a.xml', NULL, NULL, 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soapenv', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ser', 'http://www.example.com/v1/services');

$xpath = $xml->xpath( '//soapenv:Body/ser:getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest' );

print_r($xpath);
```

It gives no data.

Please let me know if i am doing it wrong.

Comment: `echo $xpath[0]->asXML();` will show you the data. everything is already fine with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite odd to see thats not working, but alternatively you could also use this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$element = $xpath->query('//soapenv:Body/ser:getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest');

foreach($element->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
    // perform your actions here
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gY6557)

Edit: Also this is another way:

```
$xml_string ='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:ser="http://www.example.com/v1/services">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest>
            <ser:buyer>
                <ser:buyerId>1233</ser:buyerId>
                <ser:toCountry>IN</ser:toCountry>
                <ser:toZip>110001</ser:toZip>
            </ser:buyer>
            <ser:item>
                <ser:id>25164</ser:id>
                <ser:categoryId>15032</ser:categoryId>
                <ser:seller>
                    <ser:sellerId>11997</ser:sellerId>
                    <ser:fromCountry>IN</ser:fromCountry>
                </ser:seller>
                <ser:transactionId>0</ser:transactionId>
            </ser:item>
        </ser:getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string, null, null, 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$soap = $xml->children($ns['soapenv']);
foreach($soap->Body as $nodes) {
    $ser = $nodes->children($ns['ser'])->getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest;
    foreach($ser->buyer as $sub_nodes) { // this can also be ->item as well

    }
}
```

Comment: Wierd to see that simplexml is not able to do this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @web-nomad yeah i was wondering about it too, anyway im glad this helped

Comment: hello @web-nomad i gaved an alternative, i wasn't proud of my first answer, if you want to use `simpleXMLelement` you could also use this revision

Comment: This looks good...hope i could upvote it a second time :) Thanks again.

Comment: @web-nomad haha no prob just glad i could help

Comment: DOM is definitely not necessary in this case, you just have to understand some of SimpleXML's peculiarities (and check sample code for typos). The `->getNamespaces(true)` call is also unnecessary in the second example, because a) you know the URLs for the namespaces already, so are better off using those in case the prefixes change; and b) you can [write `->children('ser', true)` in any version since PHP 5.2](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) if you do want to rely on the prefixes.

Comment: hello @IMSoP thanks for this great insight, learned another one

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, in your example code, you haven't actually defined `$node` anywhere:

```
$xpath = $xml->xpath( '//soapenv:Body/ser:getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest' );
print_r($node);
```

Should be:

```
$xpath = $xml->xpath( '//soapenv:Body/ser:getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest' );
$node = $xpath[0];
print_r($node);
```

Or perhaps:

```
$xpath = $xml->xpath( '//soapenv:Body/ser:getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest' );
foreach ( $xpath as $node ) {
    print_r($node);
}
```

---

Secondly, `print_r` is not great at displaying SimpleXML objects. It giving you an empty output doesn't mean that the element is empty.

For instance, try echoing the name of the node found ([Demo](http://3v4l.org/3HV6a)):

```
$xpath = $xml->xpath( '//soapenv:Body/ser:getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest' );
foreach ( $xpath as $node ) {
    echo $node->getName();
}
```

To get at its contents, you need to select the namespace they are in, with [the `->children()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php), at which point even `print_r` will be able to see them (though there are other reasons not to rely on it entirely) ([Demo](http://3v4l.org/d5qlH)):

```
$xpath = $xml->xpath( '//soapenv:Body/ser:getAnalyticalDeliveryEstimatesRequest' );
foreach ( $xpath as $node ) {
    print_r( $node->children('http://www.example.com/v1/services') ); 
}
```

Try searching for "SimpleXML with namespaces" for more examples.